# confused how to go about the query..self join or through subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, self-join

Coincidence. Have two guests with the same surname ever stayed in the hotel on the evening? Show the last name and both first names. Do not include duplicates.

[image: CLICK HERE FOR THE ER DIAGRAM]

the result should be in following format

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| last_name | first_name | first_name  |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| Davies    | Philip     | David T. C. |
| Evans     | Graham     | Mr Nigel    |
| Howarth   | Mr George  | Sir Gerald  |
| Jones     | Susan Elan | Mr Marcus   |
| Lewis     | Clive      | Dr Julian   |
| McDonnell | John       | Dr Alasdair |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What if more than two guests with the same last name stay? What have you tried? What issues are you having?

Comment: they cant..cause the  result format i gave is the actual answer

Comment: i tried the usual join and im getting the same name for both the first names..

Comment: It sounds like you've figured out how to look for the part that should be the same. You just need to add something to look for the parts that should be different. What do you think you might need to do?

Comment: Is the order of `first_name, first_name` pairs in match specified? Hint: `g1.first_name > g2.first_name` is false when the first names are the same

Answer (score 1):

below correct solution attached:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT c.last_name, c.first_name,d.first_name
  FROM booking a
        JOIN booking b ON a.booking_date <= b.booking_date AND  DATE_ADD(a.booking_date, INTERVAL (a.nights -1) DAY) >= b.booking_date AND a.booking_id != b.booking_id
        JOIN guest c ON c.id = a.guest_id
        JOIN guest d ON d.id = b.guest_id
    WHERE concat(a.guest_id, '_',  b.guest_id) IN
        (
        SELECT concat(a.id, '_',  b.id) 
        FROM guest a 
            JOIN guest b ON a.last_name = b.last_name AND a.first_name > b.first_name
        )
    ORDER BY 1
```

It uses self - join twice. First time, to obtain a table of all pairs containing bookings that occurred on given evening. From all the pairs I've selected only those where guest are sharing the same last name (here I'm using self-join second time).

Answer (score 0):

You will need a self join to join the table with self and the DISTINCT clause to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT g1.last_name, g1.first_name, g2.first_name
FROM Guests g1 
         INNER JOIN 
     Guests g2 
         ON g1.last_name = g2.last_name
```